# Batch Class to pass Account field data not compiling

Tags: apex, batch, class, account

I am trying to write a batch apex class to pass a number of field values to new fields, all on the account object. However I am having trouble compiling my class.

> Error: Class MigrateCreditSafe must implement the method: `System.Iterable<Account>` `Database.Batchable<Account>.start(Database.BatchableContext)`

```
global class MigrateCreditSafe implements Database.Batchable<Account> {

    global MigrateCreditSafe(){}

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            'SELECT Id, bottomline_creditSafeScore__c, bottomline__creditSafeCompanyType__c, bottomline__creditSafeScoreDescription__c, bottomline__creditSafeLastRefreshed__c, ' +
                                                                                     'bottomline__creditSafeLimit__c, bluetahiti_creditSafeScore__c, bluetahiti__creditSafeCompanyType__c, ' +
                                                                                     'bluetahiti__creditSafeScoreDescription__c, bluetahiti__creditSafeLastRefreshed__c, ' +
                                                                                     'bluetahiti__creditSafeLimit__c  FROM Account WHERE bottomline__creditSafeCompanyType__c != null'
        );
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope) {
       List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
       for(Account account : scope){
            bottomline_creditSafeScore__c = bluetahiti_creditSafeScore__c;
            bottomline__creditSafeCompanyType__c = bluetahiti__creditSafeCompanyType__c;
            bottomline__creditSafeScoreDescription__c = bluetahiti__creditSafeScoreDescription__c;
            bottomline__creditSafeLastRefreshed__c = bluetahiti__creditSafeLastRefreshed__c;
            bottomline__creditSafeLimit__c = bluetahiti__creditSafeLimit__c;
            // add accounts to list to be updated
            accounts.add;
       }
       update accounts; 
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {}
}
```

Comment: Try to replace Database.Batchable<Account> with Database.Batchable<SObject>

Comment: @AbhishekDaware's change will address the problem - not sure why the compiler works that way. You will also need to change the `accounts.add;` line.

Comment: Thank you! Hmm, I have made the above change, now it is saying that variables do not exist for all fields in the SOQL query - do I need to reference them differently now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems with your code. I'll comment them below:

```
// To use a QueryLocator, it must be the SObject Type
global class MigrateCreditSafe implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    /* default constructor not necessary unless you have a non-default constructor */
    // global MigrateCreditSafe(){}

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        // When possible, use an inline query instead of a string.
        // This prevents typos by allowing the compiler to validate fields.
        // Also, you don't need to query the bottomline fields, because you're not accessing their values.
        // Namespace and field name are always separated by __, not _
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            [SELECT bluetahiti__creditSafeScore__c, bluetahiti__creditSafeCompanyType__c, bluetahiti__creditSafeScoreDescription__c, 
                    bluetahiti__creditSafeLastRefreshed__c, bluetahiti__creditSafeLimit__c  
            FROM Account WHERE bottomline__creditSafeCompanyType__c != null]
        );
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope) {
       // no need to "copy the list", just use scope directly
       // List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
       for(Account account : scope){
            // You need to reference a "variable", in this case, account.
            // Looks like a missing _ on the following line, too.
            account.bottomline__creditSafeScore__c = account.bluetahiti__creditSafeScore__c;
            account.bottomline__creditSafeCompanyType__c = account.bluetahiti__creditSafeCompanyType__c;
            account.bottomline__creditSafeScoreDescription__c = account.bluetahiti__creditSafeScoreDescription__c;
            account.bottomline__creditSafeLastRefreshed__c = account.bluetahiti__creditSafeLastRefreshed__c;
            account.bottomline__creditSafeLimit__c = account.bluetahiti__creditSafeLimit__c;
            // if you needed this line, you'd have to specify the record to add:
            // accounts.add(account);
       }
       // Update the records in the database
       update scope; 
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {}
}
```

Comment: thank you so much - particularly for adding all of the comments, really helps to learn rather than just get the class working! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the start method. You don't have to return the querylocator.

Change the `Database.getQueryLocator` for `Database.query`